# FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword() not working as intended. The error.code doesn't return the thing i wanted

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

The FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword() throws  'invalid-email' when I input the wrong email format ( it worked as intended ). However, in other situations such as the correct email but the wrong password, and inputting an email that doesn't exist, it just throws **INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS** instead of **wrong-password** or **user-not-found**.

How to fix it?

```
  void signUserIn() async {
    // show loading circle
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Center(
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        });

    //TRY login
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message!); //just a test
      print(e.code);
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      } else {
        print('this code is ' + e.code);
      }
    }

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Firebase may not provide specific password-related error details. For more information on Firebase authentication errors, please refer to the official documentation at [Firebase Authentication Errors.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors)